# How to handle HTTPs json format errors from APIs in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

### INTRODUCTION

I am implementing a function for making any kind of https request to any endpoint (using the https native module). When I make a request to a specific API I get an [error response in JSON format](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=error#error). Like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "ID not found"
     }
}
```

How can I handle this kind of errors? At a first moment, I supposed that they were handled in

> request.on("error", (err) => {
> reject(err);
> });

### HTTPs Request function code

I have comment '<---------' in the relevant parts of the code

```
const https = require("https");

exports.httpsRequest = function (options, body = null) {
  /* 
    This function is useful for making requests over the HTTPs protocol 
   */

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      // Get the response content type
      const contentType =
        response.headers["content-type"] &&
        response.headers["content-type"].split(";")[0];

      // Cumulate data
      let chuncks = [];
      response.on("data", (chunck) => {
        chuncks.push(chunck);
      });

      response.on("end", () => {
        // Concat all received chunks
        let response = Buffer.concat(chuncks);

        // Some responses might be in JSON format...
        if (contentType === "application/json") {
          // Jsonify the response
          response = JSON.parse(response);
        }

        // (For the future) TODO - Check and parse more content types if needed.

        // Resolve the promise with the HTTPs response
        resolve(response); // <--------- The JSON format error responses are resolved too!!
      });
    });

    // Reject on request error
    request.on("error", (err) => {
      // <------------- At a first moment, I supposed that all error responses were handled in this part of the code
      reject(err);
    });

    // Write the body
    if (body) {
      request.write(body);
    }

    // Close HTTPs connection.
    request.end();
  });
};
```

### Question

Why the error response is not handled in request.on("error", ...) ?

Thank you. I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a different code path for when the content type isn't what you were expecting in which you call `reject()` and you also need to `try/catch` around JSON parsing errors so you can properly catch them and reject on them too.  You can solve those issues with this code:

```
exports.httpsRequest = function (options, body = null) {
  /* 
    This function is useful for making requests over the HTTPs protocol 
   */

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      // Get the response content type
      const contentType =
        response.headers["content-type"] &&
        response.headers["content-type"].split(";")[0];

      // Cumulate data
      let chuncks = [];
      response.on("data", (chunck) => {
        chuncks.push(chunck);
      });

      response.on("end", () => {
        // Concat all received chunks
        let response = Buffer.concat(chuncks);

        // Some responses might be in JSON format...
        if (contentType === "application/json") {
            try {
              // Jsonify the response
              response = JSON.parse(response);
              resolve(response);
              return;
            } catch(e) {
              reject(e);
              return;
            }
        }
        reject(new Error("Not JSON content-type"))
      });
    });

    // Reject on request error
    request.on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });

    // Write the body
    if (body) {
      request.write(body);
    }

    // Close HTTPs connection.
    request.end();
  });
};
```

FYI, libraries such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) and others listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143), all do this work for you automatically and have a lot of other useful features.  You don't really need to build this yourself.

Comment: But if error responses are in json format too, I would be able to parse them, right? So they will be resolved too as a normal response.

Comment: @VictorMolina - I don't know what that means.  You'd have to describe what else you want the function to do for me to be able to help further.  This function parses a JSON response regardless of whether the http status code is 200 or 404 or 5xx.  That's how you coded it.  If you want something different than than, then please specify the behavior you want.  The `err` event that you listen for gets network errors (such as host not found or host disconnected) when the response did not complete.

Comment: @VictorMolina - Again, I don't understand why you're reinventing the wheel here when very complete and turnkey libraries already exist for doing this such as the ones referenced in my answer.  For example, they will reject when the response status code is not 2xx.

Comment: I have solved the issue rejecting when status code is not 2xx. Anyways, I will go on with the library you mentioned to avoid losing my time. Thanks.